# Как убрать из Logwatch ошибки ^null$?

Tags: linux, https

После перехода на HTTPS в Logwatch выводятся ошибки ^null$ (соединение закрыто до получения ответа сервера) для всех хостов, которые обращаются к сайту.

Как убрать эту ошибку?

При тестировании через https://2ip.ru/server-response/ выдает:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

В самом отчете Logwatch:

```
*.** MB transferred in 7645 responses  (1xx 7645, 2xx 0, 3xx 0, 4xx 0, 5xx 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в неверном формате лог-файлов Apache. Я вернул в файле apache2.conf формат логов по-умолчанию и все стало корректно работать:

```
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\""
```